# How to set value to parent component property when a button is clicked in Child component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am new to `Angular 7` (2+) & trying my hands on `@Input` & `@Output`. However, passing data from Parent to Child component via @Input is understood & in place.

However, very basic on the other hand passing data from Child to Parent component via using `@Output` concept is understood & but the implementation is not getting right.

> Here is what I am trying. When a button is clicked in the
>   Child component, a property in the parent component should be
>   converted to Upper case & displayed.

ChildComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-child',
 templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
@Input('child-name') ChildName: string;
@Output() onHit: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {}

handleClick(name): void {
this.onHit.emit(name);
}}
```

ChildComponent.html

```
<h1> child works! </h1>
<button (click)="handleClick('eventEmitter')"> Click me! </button>
```

ParentComponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'my-dream-app';
 customerName: string = "";

catchChildEvent(e) {
 console.log(e);
}}
```

ParentComponent.html

```
 <div style="text-align:center">

 <app-child [child-name]="HelloChild"></app-child>

//Trying to bind to Custom event of child component here
<b (onHit)="catchChildEvent($event)"> 
 <i> {{customerName}} </i>
</b>
```

No error in console or binding

**From the above snippet, when the button in Child Component is clicked the parent Component's property CustomerName should get the value & displayed?**

**Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3vgorr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are emitting event from `app-child` component so attach the handler for `app-child` component to make it work.

```
<div style="text-align:center">

<app-child (onHit)="catchChildEvent($event)" [child-name]="HelloChild"></app-child>

//Trying to bind to Custom event of child component here
<b> 
 <i> {{customerName}} </i>
</b>
```

And within the ts file update value of `cutomerName` property.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-dream-app';
  customerName: string = "";

  catchChildEvent(e) {
    this.customerName = e;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`(onHit)="catchChildEvent($event)"` should be passed to `<app-child/>`

```
<app-child [child-name]="HelloChild" (onHit)="catchChildEvent($event)"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move `(onHit)="catchChildEvent($event)"` to `app-child` in parent html:

```
<app-child [child-name]="HelloChild"
    (onHit)="catchChildEvent($event)>
</app-child>
```